# Strange .txt file that has the names of different presidents inside the android system folder

Tags: dictionary

Browsing the systems files of my LG P350 I discovered a strange file inside what seems to be the XT9 files: there's a txt file called **heads_of_state.txt**, which contents are the following:

```
Hamid
Karzai
Bamir
Topi    
Sali
Berisha
Abdelaziz
Bouteflika
Ahmed
Ouyahia
Andorra
Joan
Enric 
Vives 
Sicília
Nemesi 
Marquès 
Oste
Nicolas 
Sarkozy
Christian 
Frémont
Albert 
Pintat
Jaume 
Bartumeu
José 
Eduardo 
dos 
Santos 
Paulo 
...
```

The list continues and I can spot a few presidents names. It's located in **system/usr/xt9/databases/mdb/**

What does this means?? Why the file is there? **What it is porpuose?**

For the curious, here's the full list: http://pastebin.com/V8hHYZmz

(I'm using the V10F firwmare, rooted with Gingerbread)

Comment: It's probably for the auto-complete/spellcheck dictionary so that political leaders can be added and removed more easily due to their often transient nature (but I can't prove that, so comment instead of answer).

Comment: I tried to type the names in a SMS with XT9 enabled and it didn't recognized the words or tried to correct them. Paranoia is attacking me :F

Comment: Interesting that this exists! I would agree with @eldarerathis it is most likely used for AC or spellcheck

Comment: Why would some head of state be removed from dictionary, even if (s)he is no longer in office? Besides this list is little outdated, some of those names are not in office anymore.

Comment: I insist, this words aren't used in the XT9.

Comment: @Tschareck: It's kind of moot at this point, but you don't see the value in being able to add new political leaders on the fly without having to replace the entire dictionary file? You certainly don't *have to* remove people who are no longer in office, and it seems they don't by your own observation, but even for just adding new names it would provide a lot of benefits.

Comment: @eldarerathis I think the real question here is why we need a dictionary for the name of the presidents. And why it's bundled to the stock firmware.

Comment: Is this a stock ROM?

Comment: _If_ it was a dictionary, then maybe it would make a point to have separate file, because names are common to all languages. But as @Andres (and me too) pointed out, XT9 doesn't use them.

Comment: @Flow Yup, version V10F: http://csmg.lgmobile.com:9002/swdata/WEBSW/LGP350/ACISSV/V10F_00/V10F_00.kdz. Also i found it in a LG Keyboard apk of another phone (not remember which one, because it was only the apk file)

Comment: @Tschareck: Your previous comment doesn't make any statements regarding XT9 or whether or not the file is used by it (or even a dictionary), so I have no idea what point you're even trying to make now. That seems like a complete non sequitur. Andres: Are there any other files in that directory or is this the only one? Does it look like it's been accessed at all recently? (`ls -l` should show you)

Comment: Strange.  I'll be this is left over from testing of some kind.  They probably just imported a random list to test some function.

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, there are more files in the folder:

DE.txt
EN.txt
ES.txt
FR.txt
heads_of_state.txt
IT.txt
mdb.py
mdb.txt

The files with two charaters in the name are 2 bytes long (2 hex numbers)

Python file contents are:
#!/usr/bin/env python3.0

import codecs

filein = 'heads_of_state.txt'
fileout = 'mdb.txt'

setHeads = set()
for line in codecs.open(filein, 'r', 'utf-8'):
    setHeads.add(line.strip())
liHeads = sorted(setHeads, key=lambda a: (len(a), a))
liHeads = filter(lambda a: len(a) > 4, liHeads)
codecs.open(fileout, 'w', 'utf-8').write("\n".join(liHeads))

Comment: Ooops, no formating in comments! Here are the contents of mdb.py: http://pastebin.com/n3jUrdEA Contents of mdb.txt: http://pastebin.com/WeVq2pHF

Comment: @eldarerathis ls -l result is: -rw-r--r-- root root 6265 2011-04-18 10:22 heads_of_state.txt. All the other files show the same date.

Answer (score 1):

I found a related [github repo](https://github.com/pcfighter/device_swift/) but don't know if its official or from some ROM developer. From the source the file heads_of_state.txt is listed under **IME** but has been removed in the latest commit (the only other commit). The commit message is "*Deleted uneeded LG's Calibration apk*". I can't conclude anything from this but maybe this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just found [this strange python script](http://pastebin.com/n3jUrdEA) that is included in the XT9. Note that it uses the 'heads_of_state.txt' file as input for something. Seems like a sorting script or something.

Comment: I think that's the pastebin i used to post the mdb.py contents [in this comment](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/strange-txt-file-that-has-the-names-of-different-presidents-inside-the-android/21996#comment25379_21800)

Answer (score 0):

i searched the internet for it, and the file seems is for developers testing purpose, this file can be found in other platforms either.
i found it in:
Python
Android
PHP

---

seems like `foo bar` case

Comment: Please provide a link, I didn't find any references to such a list being used for testing. Though it indeed does look a lot like `foo bar` case.